# How I make edit url for google xls editor with hidden column?

Tags: url, google-api, range, hide, xls

I am using PHP and Laravel 5.1. I am using the Google Drive API for document management.

For `.xls` and `.xlsx` files I manage to get the worksheets ids. For viewing, I am also able to hide columns by urls like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{{sheetid}}/htmlembed?single=true&gid={{worksheetid}}&range=a:d.
```

This shows columns A,B,C,D even if there are A through G columns.

This is for view only. I want a similar url for editing `xls` within a range: I want to hide some columns from being edited.